# Webpack config variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I got the following variable declared in my webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
 plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
      VERSION: JSON.stringify('5fa3b9'), 
      BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
      TWO: '1+1',
      'typeof window': JSON.stringify('object'),
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      },
    })
  ]
}
```

Now in my src/constant.jsx file, I have the following sample code

```
console.log("test", VERSION); //5fa3b9
```

The problem is in my IDE, the version variable  is underfine so I had to add "eslint-disable-next-line no-undef". My question is how to use variable "VERSION" without add the quick fix "eslint-disable-next-line no-undef"

Thanks in Advance

I tried adding "process.env" but I am getting error

```
console.log("process.env.VERSION", process.env.VERSION);
```

[image]

To log process.env, this is what I got

```
console.log("process.env", process.env);
```

[image]

Comment: Are you utilizing `process.env.VERSION` or just `VERSION`? Webpack's `DefinePlugin` doesn't pollute the `window`, instead, it appends it to the `process.env`. Click [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/envs-2p88z?file=/src/index.js) for an example.

Comment: In your example you have a .env file. I dont want to use .env file for this one because I wanted to make it dynamic. The value changes based on the environemnt.

Comment: @MattCarlotta see my changes on my question

Comment: The example was just for reference (how ENVs are applied to the process). That said, when you console log the `process` is it defined (should **not** be an empty object)?

Comment: Hi @MattCarlotta I added a screenshot of console.log(process.env). It only has two properties.

Comment: To answer your question when I console the process, its not empty

Comment: It appears that your ENVs within the DefinePlugin aren't being applied to the process which is why your IDE is complaining. Are you sure your `webpack.config.js` is being required during build time? Try adding a console log within the file and see if it's being executed.

Comment: @MattCarlotta I am not super familiar with webpack but I am not sure it matter but removing process.env and just using "VERSION" works, but I had to put in "eslint-disable-next-line no-undef" to ignore my IDE error.

Comment: Do you have a github repo or a small reproduction of the problem? Because it sounds like you're polluting the global window space if using `VERSION` works.